# How to use bootstrap size option in joomla 3.0?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I m new to joomla world. pls can any1 tell how to use bootstrap size option in joomla 3.0?

and i have 1 more question, what is the use of index.html in every modules folder which has no content in it ?

Answer (score 2):

**Second question answer**

Web servers list all its directory-content in the browser if there's not present an index.html, making it easy for attackers to click on any of the links and view the contents; worse, if it's a PHP file, which will invariably execute upon clicking. That brings three risks:

- Direct access to a PHP file exposes sensitive information (e.g. the
  server's path structure) to directly alter codes.
- It makes easier uploading hacking scripts to a site through any of
  its vulnerable component. This allows for direct web access which
  compromises the site.
- It reveals the names and size of the site's files and helps
  identifying any vulnerable extension, making it an easy target

The index.html files prevent the file listings from such exposures.

Comment: Joomla php files won't execute on clicking but for example the list of files there could tell someone what version plus like Samitha said what extensions you have.

Comment: Do you mean -small -large -mini? Those are just styles and you'd use them like any other style, in your layouts or possibly in a page suffix or module suffix and so on. Many interfaces give you the option of adding suffixes to styles

Answer (score 1):

The "bootstrap size" option in the module parameters has to be supported by the used module chrome. From the default system chromes, only the html5 one does support it. Depending on your template, there may be other chromes as well which do support it. But since it's a rather new parameter, most templates probably don't support it yet.